# A deck with 2 missing cards . A card is drawn .

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions, permutations, conditional-probability

**From a deck of cards , 2 cards are missing . Now , a 
Card is Drawn from this deck . Find the probability of this card being a king .**

Now how I’ve gone about is ,
Since 2 cards are drawn , there can be 3 cases involving a king in those 2 cards .
Either 2 kings , 1 king or no king as a part of those 2 missing cards .
Using these Ive formed cases using conditional probability, but I’m not able to go on ahead .

Comment: If no king is missing, what's the probability to draw a king?

Comment: Were the missing cards taken (or lost) from the deck with uniform probability?

Comment: @Sambo , yes , all cards were equally likely to be a part of those 2 missing cards .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The probability you are asking for is:

probability that $0$ kings are missing $*$ probability to chose a king given that $0$ kings are missing

plus

probability that $1$ king is missing $*$ probability to chose a king given that $1$ king is missing

plus

probability that $2$ kings are missing $*$ probability to chose a king given that $2$ kings are missing

So we have:

$P(king)=\frac{48*47}{52*51}*\frac{4}{50}+\frac{\begin{pmatrix}
    48 \\
    1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}*\begin{pmatrix}
    4 \\
    1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}}{\begin{pmatrix}
    52 \\
    2 \\
    \end{pmatrix}}*\frac{3}{50}+\frac{4*3}{52*51}*\frac{2}{50}=\frac{48*47}{52*51}*\frac{4}{50}+\frac{48*4}{1326}*\frac{3}{50}+\frac{4*3}{52*51}*\frac{2}{50}\simeq 0.076923$

which is actually equal to the probability of choosing a king from a normal deck(without 2 removed cards). That is because you can view the same question as:

Chose three cards from a normal deck. What is the probability of the third being a king? Of course $4/52\simeq 0.076923$.

Note: This works if the missing cards were taken each with the same probability

Comment: Thank you , this was the given answer

Comment: Great remark at the end! I didn't think of that and it's illuminating.